# change the background colour of any cell/day on the basis of events booked in full calender

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

how we can change the background colour of any cell/day on the basis of events booked on that day in full calender? for example maximum 2 events can be booked in a day ... I want to show the availability by colours of that day...e.g 1 event booked already then colour should be yellow of that cell
 2 events booked colour of that cell should be red ...otherwise green colour to show that day is fully free n any one can book any event on that day

```
 <script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

   // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    header:{
        right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
        center:'title',
        left:'prev,next,today'
        },
events:"events.php",
 dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

       document.getElementById("event").style.visibility ="visible";
        //alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
      document.getElementById("date").value= date.format();
        // change the day's background color just for fun
        $(this).css('background-color', '#A455AF');
    },
dayRender: function( date, cell )
 {   
 cell.css("background-color", "red");
  },
eventRender:function(event,element)
    {
        element.bind("dblclick" , function(){
        alert("double Click");
            });
    }

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried day render function but it doesn't give me right answer...it changes colour of all the days

Comment: Can you show how much effort you have been done? There are many ways to achieve the results.

Comment: see the code ... i am not getting it that how should i connect my events in database to change colors of those days

Comment: please help me .I am not good at coding but trying to improve it.